# Change ENTRYPOINT to container after building

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have a Dockerfile, which ends with:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/usr/local/cdt-tests/run-tests.sh"]
```

After building this container, I want to run it, but instead of executing this bash script (run-tests.sh), I want to open up a terminal window inside the container to inspect the filesystem.

If there were no ENTRYPOINT line, I could do this:

```
docker build -t x .
docker run -it x /bin/bash
```

and I could examine the container's files.

However, since there is an ENTRYPOINT, then that script will run and I cannot examine the container's files.

Is there anything I can do to get into the container to snoop around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker run` has an `--entrypoint` option

Comment: ah yes, so I could make that something like "--entrypoint /bin/bash"? Maybe be more explicit?

Comment: This might help: [How to properly override the ENTRYPOINT using docker run](https://medium.com/@opreaadrian/how-to-properly-override-the-entrypoint-using-docker-run-2e081e5feb9d)

Comment: @Cyrus: That link is pretty terrible. Mostly, it's because it doesn't always work to completely override the ENTRYPOINT. To completely blow it away in a `docker run` command, just add `--entrypoint ""` then after the image name you can just append your commands. Voila!